# Permission denied hg-git

Tags: git, github, ssh, mercurial

I'm trying to pull from a git repo and convert it to mercurial using [hg-git](http://hg-git.github.io/) with read and write access and I keep getting the following error:

```
hg clone git+ssh://github.com/user/myrepo.git
destination directory: myrepo
Permission denied (publickey).
abort: git remote error: The remote server unexpectedly closed the connection.
```

I added the private key associated with my git account to via 'git-add github_rsa' per the advise of https://github.com/schacon/hg-git/issues/161 to no avail. I've tried it both with the private repo, and changing it to public. I've also put all the necessary additions into my .hgrc file. Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: You need to use `git@github.com` instead of `github.com`, e.g.: `hg clone git+ssh://git@github.com/user/myrepo`.

Comment: `git-add` does not correlate with Mercurial|HGGit. You have (except using the correct URL, as Reimer noted): 1) Register your public key in your Github account 2) Provide evidence of private key for published private key on server-demand (OS-dependent, I can't predict your case)